# How to toggle admob view from MainViewController using Cordova

Tags: iphone, admob, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have implemented admob in my iPhone app, but the view which was created should be toggled based on my javascript's condition. So, i need to toggle that view using cordova plugins. Is there any possibility of toggling the admob view using phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by toggle you mean you want to hide the view. You could also mean you want to request a new ad but regardless I think the logic would be the same.

If you've set up your AdMob code as a plugin, you can write some js that calls into that (you might be able to do this even if you haven't). So the javascript method might look like:

```
AdMob.prototype.hideAd =
    function(options, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  var defaults = {
    'isHidden': false
  };

  for (var key in defaults) {
    if (typeof options[key] !== 'undefined') {
      defaults[key] = options[key];
    }
  }

  cordova.exec(
      successCallback,
      failureCallback,
      'AdMobPlugin',
      'hideAd',
      new Array(defaults)
  );
};
```

Then in your native code that handles the AdMob view, you can do something like this:

```
- (void)hidAd:(NSMutableArray *)arguments
         withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options {
  CDVPluginResult *pluginResult;
  NSString *callbackId = [arguments pop];

  if (!self.bannerView) {
    // Try to prevent requestAd from being called without createBannerView first
    // being called.
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR
                                     messageAsString:@"AdMobPlugin:"
                                                     @"No ad view exists"];
    [self writeJavascript:[pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:callbackId]];
    return;
  }
  BOOL isHidden = (BOOL)[[options objectForKey:@"isHidden"] boolValue];
  self.bannerView.hidden  = isHidden;

  pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
  [self writeJavascript:[pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
}
```